Compiling in Docker
I am on Ubuntu 18.04 using ROS Melodic. I'm trying to run A-LOAM (https://github.com/HKUST-Aerial-Robotics/A-LOAM) and I'm currently at the last step using Docker. After I tried running  make build , I received this error.
#0 4.501 Errors << aloam_velodyne:cmake /root/catkin_ws/logs/aloam_velodyne/build.cmake.000.log
#0 4.501 CMake Error at /opt/ros/melodic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:83 (find_package):
#0 4.501   Could not find a package configuration file provided by "geometry_msgs"
#0 4.501   with any of the following names:
#0 4.501 
#0 4.501     geometry_msgsConfig.cmake
#0 4.501     geometry_msgs-config.cmake
#0 4.501 
#0 4.501   Add the installation prefix of "geometry_msgs" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
#0 4.501   "geometry_msgs_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
#0 4.501   "geometry_msgs" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it
#0 4.501   has been installed.
#0 4.501 Call Stack (most recent call first):
#0 4.501   CMakeLists.txt:11 (find_package)

I've ensured that geometry_msgs is installed and that is in CMakeList.txt file, ros environment is sourced and that the ros installation path is included in the cmake prefix path but I'm still getting this error. Does anyone know how I can fix this?
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(aloam_velodyne)

set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE "Release")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++11")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "-O3 -Wall -g")
# Specify the Ceres installation path
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "/home/dylan/ceres-bin" ${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH})


find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  geometry_msgs
  nav_msgs
  sensor_msgs
  roscpp
  rospy
  rosbag
  std_msgs
  image_transport
  cv_bridge
  tf
)

#find_package(Eigen3 REQUIRED)
find_package(PCL REQUIRED)
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
find_package(Ceres REQUIRED)

include_directories(
  include
    ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS} 
    ${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ${CERES_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})

catkin_package(
  CATKIN_DEPENDS geometry_msgs nav_msgs roscpp rospy std_msgs
  DEPENDS EIGEN3 PCL 
  INCLUDE_DIRS include
)


add_executable(ascanRegistration src/scanRegistration.cpp)
target_link_libraries(ascanRegistration ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${PCL_LIBRARIES})

add_executable(alaserOdometry src/laserOdometry.cpp)
target_link_libraries(alaserOdometry ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${PCL_LIBRARIES} ${CERES_LIBRARIES})

add_executable(alaserMapping src/laserMapping.cpp)
target_link_libraries(alaserMapping ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${PCL_LIBRARIES} ${CERES_LIBRARIES})

add_executable(kittiHelper src/kittiHelper.cpp)
target_link_libraries(kittiHelper ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${PCL_LIBRARIES} ${OpenCV_LIBS})

This is my cmake file. Also I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 and ros melodic because I'm working on this for a school project and its instructions were to use this version so I'm just following it.

That's a generic CMake error that you don't have geometry_msgs installed in your container.
apt install ros-melodic-geometry-msgs

@dylan Also, you should not use cmake+make for ros1 packages; ros1 has it's own build command called catkin_make which you must run from top directory of a catkin workspace.

So the problem occurs because I don't have geometry_msgs in docker? I tried running apt install ros-melodic-geometry-msgs however i got this error:
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?

within docker? Usually docker containers are run as root so you shouldn't need sudo. But, maybe you just need sudo

Yep within docker. I ran with sudo and it tells me that ros-melodic-geometry-msgs is already installed. but im still receiving the same error

Did you source /opt/ros/melodic/setup.bash?

Yea, i did as well
